# How to decrease the gap between the title and the date in article?

Tags: titles, article, titling, author

I have the following .tex code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{titling}

\begin{document}

\title{Letter}
\setlength{\droptitle}{-10em}

%\author{}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

As you can see I'm not using the author field, and I have pushed the title part a bit up. Though, now the  gap between the title and the date is a bit too much for me. Is there a way to shorten that gap, in the sense that the date and all the text under it moves a bit up closer to the title?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the `titling` package, with  `\maketitlehookc`, which is what is inserted between author and date. Similarly `\maketitlehooka` denotes code inserted before title, `\maketitlehookb` is inserted between title and author and `\maketitlehookd` is inserted after date.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{titling}
\setlength{\droptitle}{-10em}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{Letter}
%\author{}
\renewcommand\maketitlehookc{\vspace{-10ex}}
\begin{document}

\title{Letter}
\maketitle
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]